# How to use .each for a dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using php/ajax to query a database and I want those records to show in a drop down via jQuery. I have this code which only shows one record. I tried to use each but then it showed as many drop downs as there were database records which obviously isn't correct. I am using json.

```
    .done(function(data) {

        var dropdown = "<select class='form-control' name='n_category' id='n_category'>" +
            "<option value=''>Please Select</option>" +
            "<option value=''>" + data[0].cat_name + "</option>" +
            "</select>";
        $("#list_cats").append(dropdown);

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `data.result[i].cat_name` wont work for you try `item.cat_name` instead

```
var dropdown ='';
.done(function(data) {
  $.each(data.result, function(i, item) {
       dropdown += "<option value=''>" + data.result[i].cat_name + "</option>";
  });​
  $("#list_cats").append( "<select class='form-control' name='n_category'>
      <option value=''>Please Select</option>"
      + dropdown
      + "</select>");
   })
```

Comment: I didn't use this exactly, but it gave me an idea which seems to have got it working. Thank you!